# Beginner coder, stuck with random generator

Tags: java

Here is my code, the object is to tally the number of double 1s, 2s, 3s, ... rolled out of 10,000 rolls. This is what i wrote so far and I cannot figure out why it is tallying up every single roll as a double

```
while (count < 10000)
{
    Random rand = new Random();  
    die1Value = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    die2Value = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    if(die1Value == die2Value)
    {
        if (die1Value == 1)
        {
            ++snakeEyes;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 2)
        {
            ++twos;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 3)
        {
            ++threes;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 4)
        {
            ++fours;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 5)
        {
            ++fives;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 6)
        {
            ++sixes;
        }
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using a switch-case construct instead of the if-else stuff makes the code more readable.

Comment: what you want to get as output?? Please specify where you get stuck??

Comment: it's an assignment for class, had to use a while loop with if-else-if.

Comment: Well the purpose of the code is to tally up the number of doubles rolled after rolling 10,000 times. I would like it that when my die1value is the same as my die2value to go into an if-else-if statement that adds ++ if the number is a 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: The way your ifs are structured you only count the trow if you get a double. Any other result is disregarded and a new throw is done. This is easy to see now that @kay reformatted your code.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `count` inside of the `if` :

```
if(die1Value == die2Value)
{
    // ...
    ++count;
}
```

And your `while` loop is on the `count` value :

```
while (count < 10000)
```

So, what you are effectively doing is discarding every throw where you don't have a double and re-throw it.

Comment: Thanks, i see the mistake now and have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

because `++count` is inside the `if(die1Value == die2Value)` block

so it will loop as many times as required to find 10000 doubles.  probably about 6 times that number.

reformatting the code above shows this more clearly.